# Google Tag Manager, Google Analytics make seperate event based on Javascript variable click

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So I'm wondering if it is at all possible report in events on Google Analytics as too which ID's were clicked without having to make multiple tags. E.g it will say the id in GA and a click count. E.g I have multiple articles that open when clicked on the same page. I want to know which articles people are opening through google analytics.

If not I'll just have to a general one that tells me how many people are clicking the articles or set up separate tags for each one. I just want the flexibility to track them without setting up a new custom javascript variable every time I create a new article.

Thanks

Custom Javascript Variable Code for when one id is selcted:

```
function() {

  var el = document.getElementById("mara");

  if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener("click", function() {
          return ("False");
      });
  } else { //IE8 support
      el.attachEvent("onclick", function() { 
          return ("False");
      });
  } return ("True");
}
```

HTML of one article that opens when the users select it show the full story:

```
<div id="mara">
            <div class="summary slideUp">
                 <div class="content">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fullStory">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="padder">
                        <h1>Content Header</h1>            
                        <p>Content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you use for your article links. Is there a specific class name you use for all your articles?

Comment: So please correct me if this is inaccurate: You want a tag that returns the ID of the article that was clicked. Also, you may want to modify your question a little. I see two things you want in the same sentence: "track the clicks for a specific id", and "one tag that outputs which id was clicked as a separate event name"

Answer (score 0):

So in your GTM you need an analytics tag. In that analytics tag you need the following:

Tag Type - Universal Analytics

Track Type - Event

These are data layer variables you must add.

Category - {{Event Category choose a name}}

Action - {{Event Action choose a name}}

Label - {{Event Label Suffix choose a name}}

Then somewhere in your js include the following. You may even be able to add a custom script in GTM

```js
function onAnaEvent(target) {

    if (dataLayer && dataLayer instanceof Array) {
        var setGtmElement = function (el) {
            return el.trim().slice(0, 40).concat('...');
        }

        dataLayer.push({
            'event' : 'choose-a-name',
            'eventAction' : setGtmElement(target.id) || setGtmElement(target.textContent) || setGtmElement(target.title) || 'Sorry, no value',
            'eventValue' : undefined, /* or a value */
            'eventCategory' : location.pathname,
            'eventLabel' : 'Choose a label'
        });
    }
}


document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    /** You probably want to filter this, so every click is not sent to GTM */
    onAnaEvent(event.target);
}, false);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to OP's questions. It looks very unrelated.

Comment: Really? Maybe I misunderstood the question. It seemed like he wanted a dynamic way to get at specific tags.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your tag manager interface, select variables from the menu, and in the column "Clicks" select "Click ID".

As per your example code the user has to click the element with the id you are looking for to expand the section; that means you can attach a GTM click handler which automatically (if enabled in the GTM interface) collects info like id, class, etc. You can access them like any other variable with curly brackets ( i.e. {{Click ID}} )

However you need to adapt your click function a little - if you do "return false" (which I gather is what you mean by 'return "false"' - a boolean value does not need quotes) the GTM click handler will not work. You'd have to use the standard  [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

You can use the ID in a event tracking Analytics tag and look into the behavior reports to see how often a click event (as event category) occured per id (set as event action).